# Equivalent function of fgets for open

Tags: c, file, stream, fopen

With `fopen()` I read the file line by line with `fgets()`.

Are there a function like `fgets()` inorder to read stream opened by `open()` ?

Comment: How about documentation? http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such function. The problem is, unless you do buffering in userspace (like `FILE*` routines do), there is no way to implement it efficiently: you'll have to `read` characters one-by-one.

On POSIX systems you can use `fdopen` to wrap a `FILE*` structure around a file descriptor, and then use `fgets`.

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to read the standard input? If so....

char line[1000]; 
FILE *fpin;

fpin=stdin; 
while(fgets(line,1000,fpin)!=NULL) printf("%s",line);